# Interface Builder tab bar view lying on its side in iPad simulator

Tags: xcode, ipad, tabs, interface-builder

I'm very confused and am hoping someone might have had this problem and be able to tell me what on earth I have done!

I had a view that was working fine - landscape

I added a new tab bar controller and hooked this new view into it.

Made sure the tab bar view controller and windows were all landscape. (EDIT in IB)

Supported device orientations are just landscape

Clicked run and was presented with basically the vertical view lying down on it's side as in this image:
http://s13.postimage.org/sabxoufrr/Screen_Shot_2012_05_07_at_13_26_06.png

Any ideas what I might have done? (or what other information you might need to help diagnose!) Interestingly, I dragged my created view (the one i tried adding to the bar controller) into a brand new project, and the same thing happened.

The view doesn't have to be connected to the tab controller in IB, but its presence in the project is enough to turn the tab view on its side

i'm confused

EDIT: nothing done in code - the only characteristic I have altered in code is the background image

EDIT: tacky solution - I just copied everything into a new project and it now works fine - but still a little perplexed as to why this happened and am interested to find out!

Comment: When you say you made sure the windows were in landscape, do you mean in IB or in your code using something like `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`?

Comment: in IB. I haven't included any code influencing the actual view, other than a background image

Comment: Give this a try: add `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{ return YES; }` to the bottom of your tab view controller's .m file. Check for spelling error as that's free-hand not copy-pasted.

Comment: Thanks, but this was already in my sheet. Decided not to waste more time on it right now and copied all data to new project - was definitely the object in IB misbehaving...oh well! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think BobbyScon was right here and I just didn't look hard enough or at the right view controller as I encountered this problem again. It isn't necessarily the new view controller that causes the problem and is more likely one of the views already in the tab bar controller set-up

So yes, make sure

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interface‌​Orientation{ return YES; }
```

(responded to question and selected as answer to remove it from unanswered list, but if BobbyScon responds with answer, will tick him instead)